# JS: Calling a function from within that function, when dealing with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, instantiation

How do I call a function from within the function, when I have multiple instances of that function?

I know I can simply call the function from within:

```
$(".mCSB_container").sortable({
    revert: true,
    scroll: true,
    update: function( event, ui ){
        new update(param1);
    },
});

function update(param1){
    if (updating){
        //If I'm already updating, I want to wait for that update to be finished
        setTimeout(function(){
            update(param1);
        }, 100)
    } else {
        updating = true;
        //Proceed with the update
        //...
        postUpdate();
    }
}

function postUpdate(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/update',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
                //...
                updating = false;
                return data;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //refresh page
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Now I'm trying to get my head around how instantiation works in JS. I know I can create a new instance simply by calling `new update(param1);`, but then what's going to happen in the timeout when I try to call the update function? I can always just create a new instance every time, but isn't that inefficient?

If I could just call the same instance from within the instance that seems like it would be ideal.

Thanks for any help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just `return this;` so you can recycle the same instance...

Comment: This is just a function, not a class -- there's no associated object.

Comment: This is a really bad example to work from if you're trying to learn about the `new` construct.

Comment: @Jeremy `return this;` doesn't seem to call the function

Comment: @Stephen Yeah, I don't really know how to use `new`, but it seems easier than trying to create objects when I don't need any child or parent objects. I just want to be able to create a new instance of a function then reference it from within the function. | And it seems like it should work

Comment: Why would you need to set the update object to call its own update routine every 100 milliseconds just to cancel out if it is already in the middle of that routine? Using the `this` keyword (but not as @Jeremy suggested) would help answer your question, but in this context it doesn't make sense to me. Can you provide a clearer example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jesse The issue is that I'm pulling data back from the server, and just to make sure I don't have to deal with conflicting data, I don't want an update to happen when one is already taking place. The `update(param1)` function needs to rely on knowing what's on the server, and if 2 instances are running at the same time, then they will post conflicting data to the server. When the data comes back successfully from the server, I can ensure that the data won't conflict.

Comment: @Jesse I don't think so, the example is simply that I keep track of the list positions which I post to the server. I have a global `databasePositionArray` which keeps track of the positions, then when I update I check where then new `currentPositionArray` is different from the `databasePositionArray`... I then post only what needs to be updated to the server. The issue is that the `databasePositionArray` won't reflect what's really on the database unless I wait to do position updates until I get a confirmation back from the server.

Comment: I can just do a _for_ within the instance that just keeps checking until the server relays the data, but I don't like the extra code, and it makes the code less readable for me if I have to do that every time in this kind of situation.

Comment: I am working on a loose example for you, although I suggest that you read the fundamentals of object-oriented JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and explore a few of the [multitude of other resources](http://google.com/search?q=object+oriented+javascript) since there are different ways of doing OOP in JavaScript. You stated that using the `new` keyword seems easier than trying to create objects, but that is exactly what one would do with the `new` keyword in many programming languages regardless of inheritance.

Comment: After looking through the JS OOP examples, it seems that they deal mainly with inheritance. They are helpful in that, I have a poor understanding of how instantiation works in JS. But in this particular example, my object/function isn't related to any others. I simply want to be able to have the ability to create new objects so that in the event something is called twice they don't interfere with each other (The situation that would occur if I didn't create a new instance). Thanks a ton for the help @Jesse